# Something like jQuery live, but not for events, rather for jQuery objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If you want to create a handler for elements with the `tab` class, event the elements which would be added later, you use:

```
$('.tab').click(function(){
    // Doing something here.
});
```

Now, my question is, is there anything similar to this late-binding event handler for object selection? In other words, what if I cache the jQuery object of elements with class `tab` in a variable called tabs:

```
var tabs = $('.tab');
```

Now, if I add another element with class `tab`, it won't be added to the `tabs` variable. Is it anyway to get the `tabs` variable late-bound to the collection of objects with `tab` class?

Comment: How about not caching it at all? Any solution would be just a convoluted way of calling `$('.tab')` every time you needed your `tabs`.

Comment: What is the bigger picture? Efficiency? I doubt such thing exists, and really can't see the point of such a thing without having more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [live query](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) plugin.

> Live Query also has the ability to fire a function (callback) when it matches a new element

Beware of over using this however as it scans the dom every 20 milliseconds to look for changes which can degrade overall page performance.

Comment: But the OP is not interested in "real" events like click or hover - he's after event like "element with such class has been added to the document"

Comment: Ah, his question refers to click which put me off. Updated with a new solution to his issue.